# pyopencvを使った動画出力でGStreamerのエラー

Tags: python, opencv

下記のようなプログラムを組んで実行したいのですがエラーが出てしまい、実行できません。
プログラム自体は[こちら](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video)にある動画を保存するプログラムを海外掲示板などを参考に一部改変したものです。

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc,20.0,(640,480))

while(cap.isOpend()):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

エラーは以下のようになります。

```
** (python:14547): CRITICAL **: gst_missing_encoder_message_new: assertion 'gst_caps_is_fixed (encode_caps)' failed

(python:14547): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_post_message: assertion 'message != NULL' failed
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: cannot link elements
) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 1335
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "videoRecorder.py", line 9, in <module>
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc,20.0,(640,480))
cv2.error: /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1335: error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot link elements
in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open
```

Gstreamerというライブラリ？が関係してるようなのですが、解決方法を掴めずにいます。
これはopencv自体のバグなのでしょうか？

Comment: gstreamer1-libav.x86_64という動画関係のgstreamerのライブラリをインストールしたことで自己解決しました。
大変お恥ずかしいことに、while文のcap.isOpenedだった場所をcap.isOpendにしていました。
こちらの質問を閲覧してくれた方々、ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決されてよかったです。回答を自分で書いて後でベストアンサーにしておくと、質問が解決済みと分かりやすくなります。

Comment: @entoさん、了解しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gstreamer1-libav.x86_64という動画関係のライブラリをインストールすることで解決いたしました。
また、大変お恥ずかしいことに、while文の`cap.isOpened`だった箇所を`cap.isOpend`と記述していました。

質問を閲覧してくださった方々、ありがとうございました。
質問を修正してくださった、ジェフリーさん、コメントをくださったentoさんありがとうございました。

Comment: 今後同じエラーになって回答を探しにきた人向けに、解決策が明確になるように編集してみました。こうして他の人の役に立つ情報を残されたのですから、どちらかというと威張るくらいでもいいと思いますよ！